# Append to list error: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list

```
graph = []
for double in change:
    year = str(double[1].year)
    month = str(double[1].month)
    day = str(double[1].day)
    hour = str(double[1].hour)
    string = '{ x: new Date('+year+','+month+','+day+','+hour+'), '+'y:'+str(double[0])+'}, '
    graph.append(string)    
    graph = ''.join(graph)
    print "Graph is:"+graph
```

I do not understand why this does not work and gives the error `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Note that `change` is a list of lists. In this specific case, it looks like this:

```
[[1.0, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 3, 1, 0)], [2.0, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 3, 2, 0)]]
```

The goal is to get:

`'{ x: new Date(2015,7,3,1), y:1.0}, ', '{ x: new Date(2015,7,3,2), y:2.0}, '`

Comment: Clearly, `graph` is not a list but a string by the time the exception happens. You oversimplified your code, because that error won't happen with this version.

Comment: @Kevin The above code gives the same error, for all intents and purposes, they are the exact same, posting my full code would cause confusion and would add complexity

Comment: No, the above code does **not** give the same error. That's because `graph` is never rebound to a string.

Comment: Yes this code above will not give the error you are getting. @Reach_Down

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are correct, I am furiously trying to figure out what is going on, will update accordingly

Comment: @Reach_Down: somewhere *else* in your code `graph` is reused for something else and bound to a string, most likely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated accordingly

Comment: @Reach_Down: did you test this smaller piece of code? Because it too won't show the error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The above code is what I am using, exactly, and it gives the error

Comment: `graph` is clearly a list and this code will not give such an error

Comment: @heinst Yet it does...Please try and provide a useful solution.

Comment: @Reach_Down: no, you have **more** code than this. The code you posted here won't show the error because the part that causes the problem is missing. When I run the code posted here with your sample data, I get `['{ x: new Date(2015,7,3,1), y:1.0}, ', '{ x: new Date(2015,7,3,2), y:2.0}, ']`.

Comment: @Reach_Down You must be reusing `graph` somewhere that you are not showing us because your example works fine

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated to reflect the exact code

Comment: @IanAuld  Try it now, updated

Comment: Try changing the name of graph to something else just to test it. Works fine for me as well so graph MUST be used elsewhere for something.

Comment: `''.join(graph) print "Graph is:" + str(graph)`

Comment: I don't understand how you thought the very next line where you reassign `graph` was unimportant.

Comment: @Modred The exact code is up there, I updated it, if you use it, it will throw an error

Comment: @IanAuld My apologies, working with little sleep

Comment: @Reach_Down: and what do you think `graph` is after setting it to the result of a `str.join()` call?

Answer (score 1):

You were trying concatenate a string and list, which is why you were getting that error.

```
import datetime
change = [[1.0, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 3, 1, 0)], [2.0, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 3, 2, 0)]]
graph = []
for double in change:
    year = str(double[1].year)
    month = str(double[1].month)
    day = str(double[1].day)
    hour = str(double[1].hour)
    string = '{ x: new Date('+year+','+month+','+day+','+hour+'), '+'y:'+str(double[0])+'}'
    graph.append(string)

print ', '.join(graph)
```

Comment: Very true...what was i thinking :p

Answer (score 0):

```
graph = []
for double in change:
    year = str(double[1].year)
    month = str(double[1].month)
    day = str(double[1].day)
    hour = str(double[1].hour)
    string = '{ x: new Date('+year+','+month+','+day+','+hour+'), '+'y:'+str(double[0])+'}, '
    graph.append(string)

graph = ''.join(graph)
print "Graph is:"+graph
```